# Trouble Deploying Django

Tags: python, django, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to deploy a Django app, however I am running into some issues with NPM. When running the script I am given an error output by npm, which hopefully has all the information needed.

I am using Digital Ocean as the server and their one click django application on Ubuntu Linux.

I've tried the common stuff such as clearing NPM's cache, checking permissions on the .npm folder and running as sudo however the issue persists. Anybody encountered this?

```
Checking name of current directory
Deleting old *.pyc files
Checking whether GAE is installed in /home/django/django_project/oppia/../oppia_tools/google_appengine_1.8.8/google_appengine
Checking if webtest is installed in third_party
done
Checking if node.js is installed in /home/django/django_project/oppia/../oppia_tools
Checking whether jsrepl is installed in third_party
Installing CoffeeScript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/1.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/1.2.0
coffee-script@1.2.0 ../node_modules/coffee-script
Installing uglify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-to-browserify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/0.1.34
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-to-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/0.1.34
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/camelcase
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decamelize
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/window-size/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/camelcase
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/decamelize
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/django/django_project/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/util.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/django/django_project/oppia/../oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/bin/node" "/home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/bin/npm" "install" "uglify-js"
npm ERR! cwd /home/django/django_project/oppia
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/django/django_project/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/django/django_project/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: camelcase@'^1.0.2'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.1.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:684:10)
npm ERR!     at /home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:606:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/django/django_project/oppia/../oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/bin/node" "/home/django/django_project/oppia_tools/node-0.10.1/bin/npm" "install" "uglify-js"
npm ERR! cwd /home/django/django_project/oppia
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/window-size/0.1.0
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/django/django_project/oppia/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I forked the Google Code project to my GitHub which you can find here: https://github.com/BitSpaceDevelopment/oppia but the original project is here: https://code.google.com/p/oppia/

Comment: It looks like Oppia is [built to be deployed on Google App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/oppia/wiki/DeployingOppia); if you've modified the project to make it suitable to deploy on a standard server, you should describe those modifications in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I currently have not modified it but the issue I am running on is before even getting to the deploy part. I am trying to build the project and npm is throwing some errors. I have tried manually installing the pieces it is complaining about and they work fine.